# Boolean Logic: How can I simplify this IF statement?

Tags: if-statement, boolean-logic, demorgans-law

I inherited some code that contains an IF statement I'd like to reduce if possible. 
It is, in essence, a simple IF (A or B) THEN.  But it gets tricky because A and B are generalizations of other expressions.

Question: How can I re-express this, if possible, in simpler terms?

Here's the original IF statement....
 For clarity, I've substituted brackets and braces for parentheses.

```
IF ( { W & X & Y & Z } or  { C & D & [ ( F & G) or (H & G) or (F & J) ] } )
/* Comment: For what it's worth: (Z = not c) */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a logic perspective, you can't. There are no duplicate variables (`Z = ¬C` doesn't help much) and because of the nesting normal forms will be longer than this.  This seems to be as short as it gets.

From a programming perspective, if absolute maximum speed is less important than readability (or you've got a decent compiler) I would re-group them in a way that makes the decision structure more clear (which of these are related from a (program execution) logic point of view?), even if that duplicates checks to certain variables (assuming that these are not function calls).  I'd also split this up into several separate definitions and only combine the results inside the `if`.

Comment: .@nobody: Thanks for taking a look. Fortunately, none of these are function calls and speed is not a priority. I just added some plain English comments to explain the logic and left well enough alone.